# Theorem $4.3.12$ on ( Mathématiques en BCPST Tome 1 Pascal BEAUGENDRE )

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f\in \mathbb{R}^{I}$ and $x_0 \in \stackrel{\ \circ}{I} = \mathrm{int}(A)$

Show that  $$\left.\begin{matrix} f \text{ is continuous at } x_0 \\
f \text{ is differentiable at all } x \in I \setminus \{x_0\}\\
f' \text{ has a limit } l\text{ at } x_0 
 \end{matrix}\right\rbrace  \implies  f \text{ is differentiable at } x_0 \text{ and } f'(x_0)=l  $$

I tried to use the 
**Mean value theorem:**

Let $f : [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on the closed interval $[a,b]$, and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$, where $a <b$ Then there exists some $c \in (a,b)$ such that

$$ f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$

**Edit** 
Reference for this theorem is here in wikipedia in french i don't know its name in english 
if someone knows tell us please

[Dérivabilité et prolongement](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9rivabilit%C3%A9)

You can chec also this theorem here in google books with its detailed proof :

**Theorem $4.3.12$ Page $141-142$**

book call it  :

[**Mathématiques en BCPST Tome 1 : analyse et probabilités pour la classe de première année (cours - exercices et devoirs. Pascal BEAUGENDRE**](https://books.google.co.ma/books?id=yGTqAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA141&dq=th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me%20de%20la%20limite%20de%20la%20d%C3%A9riv%C3%A9e&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KufIVMW0Caa7ygOCwoCwCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me%20de%20la%20limite%20de%20la%20d%C3%A9riv%C3%A9e&f=false)

Comment: For the next time, click on the "read on another language" button on the left (or at the bottom of you're using the mobile version of Wikipedia) so you can find trustworthy translation of technical words ;-)

Comment: i did click in version of english but unfortunately doesn't contain that theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f'$ has limit $l$ at $x_0$, then given $\epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$, s.t. $|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f'(x)-l|<\epsilon$

Consider such $x$,， by MVT($f$  differentiable on open interval, continuous on closed interval), we have

$$\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(\xi)$$
where $\xi$ lies between $x,x_0$. Then by triangle inequality

$$|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-l|\le|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-f'(\xi)|+|f'(\xi)-l|$$ hence the first part vanishes, and second part $<\epsilon$, by definition, we get the result.

Comment: @Educ Please see if you still have question.

Comment: why you support them to hold my question as unclear even it's theorem in wikipedia

Comment: @Educ I am sorry. At that time there is some typo in the question. I have voted to reopen.